# structures in c to store details of employees and print those who get more than 10000

Tags: c, structure

I'm supposed to get details of 4 employees and print the details of those who get salary more than 10000. I'm not supposed change the structure of the program. When i compile this code i dont get any error but the output is just

```
0  0.00
0  0.00
0  0.00
```

I cant find where i'm doing the mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct employee
{ int id;
    char name[10];
    float sal;
} EMP;

void init_emp_rec(EMP out_rec[]);
void print_emp_rec(EMP out_rec[]);

void emp_recordMain(EMP emp_rec[], EMP out_rec[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(emp_rec[i].sal>10000)
        {
            out_rec[i].id=emp_rec[i].id;
            strcpy(out_rec[i].name,emp_rec[i].name);
            out_rec[i].sal=emp_rec[i].sal;
        }
    }        
}

void init_emp_rec(EMP out_rec[])
{
    memset(out_rec, 0, sizeof(EMP)*4);
}

void print_emp_rec(EMP out_rec[])
{   
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)    
    {
        printf("%d %s %.2f", out_rec[i].id, out_rec[i].name, out_rec[i].sal);
        if(i!=2){printf("\n");}
    }
}

main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int i;
    EMP emp_rec[4];
    EMP out_rec[4];
    init_emp_rec(out_rec);
    init_emp_rec(emp_rec);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&emp_rec[i].id);
        scanf("%s",&emp_rec[i].name);
        scanf("%0.2f",&emp_rec[i].sal);
    }    
    emp_recordMain(emp_rec, out_rec);
    print_emp_rec(out_rec);
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong `i` loop counter in every function, change `3` to `4`. Also change the `scanf` format from `"%0.2f"` to `"%f"`. Also for the `"%s"` format, remove the `&` in front of `&emp_rec[i].name`.

Comment: Related: If `out_rec` is supposed to contain copies of only records with salaries exceeding 10000, I would advise you use a separate index for `out_rec` when making the copies (which can be done with structure assignments, btw). Otherwise you'll have "holes" in your `out_rec` array for matching indexes of `emp_rec` that did not meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rec[i].name` is already an address to a string so you should use:

```
  scanf("%s",emp_rec[i].name);
```

Also, you should not use format specifiers ("0.2") while reading the float:

```
  scanf("%f",&emp_rec[i].sal);
```

I feel that there are other things to fix, but I don't want to jeopardise your exercise :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to change your code a little:

```
scanf("%f",&emp_rec[i].sal);
```

"%0.2f" would treat 20000 like 0.

Comment: With `"%0.2f"`, GCC in particular warns about the zero width, and considers the `.` an unknown conversion type character... so it won't even scan a float.